# a sortable table fixing

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

**When I change their rankings, I want their id to remain constant.**

When I wanted to make Banana the first. And the one I'm dragging, Banana, is automatically 1., Apple 2. Organge 3. it will be. So I want the table numbers to remain constant.

how do I do that

```js
$(function () {
  $("#sortable tbody")
    .sortable({
      cursor: "move",
      placeholder: "sortable-placeholder",
      helper: function (e, tr) {
        var $originals = tr.children();
        var $helper = tr.clone();
        $helper.children().each(function (index) {
          // Set helper cell sizes to match the original sizes
          $(this).width($originals.eq(index).width());
        });
        return $helper;
      }
    })
    .disableSelection();
});
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
 
* {
  font-family : "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  }
.responsive-table {
  overflow : auto;
  }
table {
  width           : 100%;
  border-spacing  : 0;
  border-collapse : collapse;
  white-space     : nowrap;
  }
table th {
  background       : #bdbdbd;
  }
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color : #f2f2f2;
  }
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color : #e6e6e6;
  }
th,
tr,
td {
  text-align : center;
  border     : 1px solid #e0e0e0;
  padding    : 5px;
  }
img {
  font-style : italic;
  font-size  : 11px;
  }
.fa-bars {
  cursor     : move;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="responsive-table">
  <table id="sortable">
    <tr class="ui-state-default">
      <th>Drag Row</th>
      <th>Id</th>
      <th>Fruit</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Image</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></td>
      <td data-id="1">1</td>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td><img src="" alt="noImage" width="30px" height="25px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></td>
      <td data-id="2">2</td>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td><img src="" alt="noImage" width="30px" height="25px"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></td>
      <td data-role="test" data-id="3">3</td>
      <td>Banana</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><img src="" alt="noImage" width="30px" height="25px"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

CODEPEN LİNK: `https://codepen.io/orist/pen/bVmzoK`

When I change their rankings, I want their id to remain constant.

Comment: The ids (at least for me in the codepen - the stackoverflow code snippet does not work) are constant. What is the problem?

Comment: When I change their rankings, I want their id to remain constant. Can u open codepen link : 'https://codepen.io/orist/pen/bVmzoK'

Comment: garfield wants the IDs to always be in descending order – 1, 2, 3 – no matter how things are rearranged

Comment: So it's not id (the identificator of the element), but order of the element.  You can listen to event, for example https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-change and change the numbers as needed

Comment: Actually, 3. person 1.ye i want the sort id to be 1 automatically when I fetch it.